# Is there a method of killing that seems to be universally effective in the Arrowverse?

Tags: dc, arrowverse

Effectiveness is defined as a character dying or temporarily dying. Universal is defined as it has been used against all types of characters effectively. All types of characters is defined as species or power (i.e Kryptonians, speedsters, Daxamites, metahumans, etc.)

Comment: This feels a bit broad. Would you accept anything that has worked on everyone it's been used on? LIke, if only two characters have been hit with a disintegration ray and it worked both times (but they were both humans), does that count?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots yes, I would. But mainly I am looking if there is a common way that humans, aliens, and metas die.

Comment: https://listofdeaths.fandom.com/wiki/Arrowverse might be handy, but it's a bit much for meto sit down with today.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots it seems like there is no commonality, other than death :  )

Comment: Red sky antimatter wave seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

**Shooting Homicides — Shooting is by far the most universally effective form of death**

Shooting deaths are universally the most effective form of death on *Arrow*, far outnumbering the next universally effective form of deaths being stabbing, and neck-breaking.

Most interestingly, disintegration of the whole victim (particularly supernatural disintegrations) appears to be the least effective — as this form of death also universally ends in the disintegrated victim being later resurrected. This also includes all the various incinerations of characters played by show lead actors by Vandal Savage using the Staff of Horus in *Arrow* Season 4 cross-over lead-up to Legends of Tomorrow, “Legends of Yesterday.”

Notes: Arrow, by far has the most on-screen deaths of all of the other Arrowverse shows, *nearly combined*, and the most common death on *Arrow* is through shooting.

Comment: How far down the list is the titular method of shooting with an arrow?  Or does "shooting" as used here imply both firearms and bows?

Comment: There’s a bit of extrapolation required, but by my estimate, there are “a heckuva a lot” onscreen deaths by firearms, usually downing someone by head or center of mass, which typically has high certainty of death. Some of these might also include arrow shots in my count establishing “a heckuva alot”; however “death by arrow,” specifically that includes stabbing by arrow as well as ranged shot by arrow might combined also amount to “a lot.” I kept out of count the “mass deaths” like Markov Device earthquake which episodes confirmed killed 503 people, but not all of those were shown.

Comment: Of course “Flashpoint” like events which killed entire timelines — billions, trillions, nearly infinite throughout the universe of the ended timeline — also were not considered.